# не работает атрибут 'maxlength' в input

Tags: html, html5

на ограничения символов не работают атрибуты `size` и `maxlength`
может я не верно записал или в `HTML 5` они не работают, подскажите пожалуйста в чем дело ?

```
<input type="number" size="5" maxlength="5">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Атрибут maxlenght** - устанавливает максимальное число символов, которое может быть введено пользователем **в текстовом поле**.

Тоже самое с `size`, работает только на текстовые поля типа `text` и `password`.

Для вашей задумки воспользуйтесь атрибутами `max` и `min`.

Comment: `max` и `min` пробовал, не работает с типом `number`

Comment: @TomSky, что вы подразумеваете под не работает? Как по мне вполне работает, при попытке отправить форму с неверным значением, пользователю будет показана ошибка ввода: https://jsfiddle.net/dxhhd0vm/

Answer (score 0):

боюсь показаться смешным, однако у меня была такая же проблема, но решилась просто: сохранить внесенные изменения в html документ в редакторе и обновить страницу в браузере. Часто забываю это делать, так как только начал учиться. Надеюсь, что смог помочь.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/766079)

Answer (score -1):

```
<INPUT type="text" maxlength="5" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">


<script>
function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) return false;
       return true;
    };
</script>
```

Делаем тип text и даем возможность ввода только цифр

Comment: Ваш код никак не отвечает на вопрос.

Comment: Ответ прост, никак. Можно заюзать Angular конечно. Если не любите javasript вот вам <input type="number" onKeyDown="if(this.value.length==5) return false;" />